# How to trigger CRM retrieve message plugin by querying web service

Tags: dynamics-crm

I've written a CRM plugin that listens to the retrieve message of one of my custom entities.

This plugin is triggered correctly when that entity is accessed from the CRM UI or from another plugin. But it is not triggered when the entity is read from the OData web service. I suspect this is by design, but I would still like to find a way to make the plugin trigger when the entities are accessed through the web service.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register your plugin step on the `RetrieveMultiple` message instead.